# Timeshift an RX sequence into a batch after a quiet period?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I need my system to send an email summarising things that have happened after a period of inactivity. How can I do this with RX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
IObservable<IList<T>> query =
    source.Publish(hot => hot.Buffer(() => hot.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))));
```